# Font Not Displaying Properly in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to save a pdf from illustrator and I have never had this issue, the font looks fine in illustrator, but when I save the pdf and open the pdf in a pdf viewer the "i" character now has a box beneath the text but the dot of the i stays there.

When viewed in illustrator:

[image: When Viewed In Illustrator]

When viewed in a PDF viewer:

[image: When Viewed In A PDF Browser]

I know that when the square shows up it means the font you are trying to use isn't there however the other characters appear fine, it just seems to be the I which is odd. The font passed verification (for reference it is Playfair Display

Does anyone know how to fix this or why this could be occurring? Am I exporting wrong(I've never had this issue before with exporting)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I solved my question while writing it. The font that was installed was a variable font type (I downloaded it from Google), for some reason it doesn't seem to want to play nicely in a pdf (maybe I'm saving it incorrectly?). I deleted the variable font and installed the static versions of the font and now the issue has gone away.

I don't know too much about variable fonts but it seems like they are maybe a bit finicky?

Hope this can help others!